# C# MongoDB multiple type serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I use MongoDB C# driver (2.13.2) and I work with such input data in the collection where one **Value** field can be *null*, *true*, *"string value"* or an *object*.

```
{
  "ItemId": UUID("13202a78-668d-4b17-9aac-78524d50925e"),
  "FieldValue": {
    "FieldName" : "IsCity",
    "Value": true
  }
},
{
  "ItemId": UUID("26566f9a-712d-44fe-9baa-722aa53e0038"),
  "FieldValue": {
    "FieldName" : "Address",
    "Value": "Address"
},
{
  "ItemId": UUID("6640a83a-a47d-4016-9d50-70c41425e099"),
  "FieldValue": {
    "FieldName" : "Address",
    "Value": {
      "Data1": "String",
      "Data2": [
        UUID("a9bde160-22af-4cf7-a201-57db8b392c4d")
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my classes for serialization:

```
class MyData {
  public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
  public MyFieldValue FieldValue { get; set; }
}

class MyFieldValue {
  public string FieldName { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, object> Value { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using a dictionary or a BSON document, but due to **true** or **false** values, an exception occurs during serialization: *Cannot deserialize a 'Dictionary<String, Object>' from BsonType 'Boolean'.* How can I serialize a **Value** that can be very different?

Alternatively, when serialized, convert a Boolean value or string into an object of the form { "value": "true" }. Then all the values will be a dictionary. But how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you just want `BsonValue` instead of `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: If the data type of the `Value` property is unknown at compile time, you can either use `object` or `dynamic` (which is basically `object` with some compiler magic).

Answer (score 0):

The topic you are discussing is referred to as "Schema Versioning".  See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-schema-versioning-pattern.

For C# specifically the MongoDB driver has some strategies for schema versioning.  See https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/schema_changes/

One topic not described in the online documentation is the ability to use a generic type and convert to your specific type.  This is not a preferred approach because it takes extra work on the application to serialize and convert, but if you are not concerned with these performance implications then this might be an idea worth considering.

Here is an example of using a generic type (`BsonDocument`) to illustrate no C# type limitations imposed on the data.  I am using your exact documents in your original question (post).

**Test.cs**

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

public class Test
{
    private MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient client;
    private MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase database; 
    private MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> collection;

    public Test()
    {
        #pragma warning disable 0618
        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
        MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.GuidSerializer(MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard));
        
        string uri = "mongodb://testuser:mysecret@localhost:50011,localhost:50012,localhost:50013/csharptest?replicaSet=replSet&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&readConcernLevel=majority";
    
        this.client = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient(uri);
        this.database = client.GetDatabase("csharptesting");
        this.collection = database.GetCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>("somecollection");

        // CLEAR OUT ALL THE PRIOR TEST RECORDS
        this.collection.DeleteMany(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument());
    }

    public void insertRecords() 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Begin insert record 1...");
        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document1 = new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
             {"ItemId", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonBinaryData(new System.Guid("13202a78-668d-4b17-9aac-78524d50925e"), MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard)},
             {"FieldValue", 
                new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
                    {"FieldName", "IsCity"},
                    {"Value", true}
                }
             }
        };
        this.collection.InsertOne(document1);
        System.Console.WriteLine("End insert record 1");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Begin insert record 2...");
        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document2 = new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
             {"ItemId", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonBinaryData(new System.Guid("26566f9a-712d-44fe-9baa-722aa53e0038"), MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard)},
             {"FieldValue", 
                new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
                    {"FieldName", "Address"},
                    {"Value", "Address"}
                }
             }
        };
        this.collection.InsertOne(document2);
        System.Console.WriteLine("End insert record 2");


        System.Console.WriteLine("Begin insert record 3...");
        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document3 = new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
             {"ItemId", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonBinaryData(new System.Guid("6640a83a-a47d-4016-9d50-70c41425e099"), MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard)},
             {"FieldValue", 
                new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
                    {"FieldName", "Address"},
                    {"Value", 
                        new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument {
                            { "Data1", "String" },
                            { "Data2", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonBinaryData(new System.Guid("a9bde160-22af-4cf7-a201-57db8b392c4d"), MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard)}
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
        };
        this.collection.InsertOne(document3);
        System.Console.WriteLine("End insert record 3");
    }

    public void find()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Find data...");

        foreach(MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument record in this.collection.Find(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument()).ToList())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(record);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("End find data");
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Full_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            test.insertRecords();
            test.find();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Begin insert record 1...
End insert record 1
Begin insert record 2...
End insert record 2
Begin insert record 3...
End insert record 3
Find data...
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619d15d9bd6b57dece960714"), "ItemId" : UUID("13202a78-668d-4b17-9aac-78524d50925e"), "FieldValue" : { "FieldName" : "IsCity", "Value" : true } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619d15d9bd6b57dece960715"), "ItemId" : UUID("26566f9a-712d-44fe-9baa-722aa53e0038"), "FieldValue" : { "FieldName" : "Address", "Value" : "Address" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("619d15d9bd6b57dece960716"), "ItemId" : UUID("6640a83a-a47d-4016-9d50-70c41425e099"), "FieldValue" : { "FieldName" : "Address", "Value" : { "Data1" : "String", "Data2" : UUID("a9bde160-22af-4cf7-a201-57db8b392c4d") } } }
End find data
```

**Conclusion**

you can access the queried documents using a generic type, such as BsonDocument() and access field by field.  With this approach you could transform this BsonDocument to your specific type, but this would require a custom transformer method.

Comment: A good answer, perhaps the whole object as BsonDocument is a lot, and one field, as suggested by @Llama, will do.